# Importing MongoDB from MongoDB 90m objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, garbage-collection

I am trying to modify and re-add same objects to a collection.

As I watch from process list, memory usage regularly increases and the system crashes after about 1-1.5 GB of usage.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/muJE928.jpg]

> Connected to 'whatsonline' database
>
> <--- Last few GCs --->
>
> 263718 ms: Scavenge 1401.0 (1457.9) -> 1401.0 (145.9) MB, 16.9 / 0
>   ms (+ 5.0 ms in 1 steps since last GC) [allocation failure]
>   [incremental marking delaying mark-sweep].   266019 ms: Mark-sweep
>   1401.0 (1457.9) -> 1397.7 (1456.9) MB, 2301.4 / 0 ms (+ 7.0 ms in 2 steps since start of marking, biggest step 5.0 ms) [last resort gc].
>   268107 ms: Mark-sweep 1397.7 (1456.9) -> 1399.6 (1457.9) MB, 2087.4 /
>   0 ms [last resort gc].
>
> <--- JS stacktrace --->
>
> ==== JS stack trace =========================================
>
> Security context: 0000019635FE3AD1 
>       1: emit [events.js:~130] [pc=00000055BB5E4FCD] (this=000003B339745331 ,type=0000019635FEC629
>   )
>       2: arguments adaptor frame: 2->1
>       3: read [_stream_readable.js:~258] [pc=00000055BB645B3A] (this=000003B339745331 ,n=0000019635F04189 )
>       4: arguments adaptor frame: 0->1
>       5: _tickCallback [internal/process/next_tick.js:~87] [pc=00000...
>
> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of
>   memory

Here is the code I'm using:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');

var Server = mongo.Server,
    Db = mongo.Db,
    MongoClient = mongo.MongoClient,
    BSON = mongo.BSONPure;

var server = new Server('localhost', 27017, {auto_reconnect: true});
db = new Db('whatsonline', server, {safe: true});


db.open(function(err, db) {
    if(!err) {
        console.log("Connected to 'whatsonline' database");
        db.collection('numaralar', {safe:true}, function(err, collection) {
            collection.createIndex( { name: 1, tel: 1 }, { unique: true,dropDups : true });
            if (err) {
                console.log("The 'numaralar' collection doesn't exist. Creating it with sample data...");
            }

        //console.log(collection);
        var stream = collection.find().stream();
            stream.on('data', function(doc) {
                var tarz=ekle(doc.name,doc.tel.replace(/\D/g,''));
            });
            stream.on('end',function(){ console.log('query ended'); });
            stream.on('close',function(){ console.log('query closed'); });

        });
    }
});


function ekle(isim,no)
{
    db.collection('numaralar1', function(err, collection) {
        collection.insert({tel:no,name:isim}, {safe:true,continueOnError: true,keepGoing: true}, function(err, result) {
            if (err) {
                //res({'error':'An error has occurred'});
            } else {
                //console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result));
                //res(result);
            }
        });
    });
return true;
}
```

Comment: have you tried bulk insert or insertMany operations instead of inserting single document at a time?

Comment: again, I'm not positive if NodeJS is a good choice for very long running processes and believe you need a modern concurrent and parallel aware programming language but again, it's my opinion so please no holy war.

Comment: The "basic" issue here is that `.insert()` is "async" and you don't actually wait for completion before moving on to the next item in the stream. There are of course other issues here. 1. The `dropDups` option you have on the index does not work with MongoDB anymore. It's near a moot point but you should be aware of it. 2. I kind of get the feeling that all you really want to do here is a regex replace on some of the data ( and possibly remove some duplicates ), in which case the "new collection" is overkill here and you would be better off just updating the existing collection data instead.